# Получение текста с владки JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing

использую JTabbedPane в "текстовом редакторе" и хне знаю как получить содержимое вкладки JTabbedPane. Пробовал делать через getTabComponentAt() он возвращает null. Так происходит открытие уже существующего текстового файла, а как получить текст из JTextArea, который будет в дальнейшем уже изменен?

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(res));
choiceFile.addTab(String.valueOf(workFile.getName()), area);
choiceFile.setSelectedIndex(i);
i++;
```

Пробовал сделать вот так:

```
System.out.println(choiceFile.getTabComponentAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения текста с выбранной вкладки необходимо получить компонент и привести его к типу JTextArea, после чего с помощью метода getText() можно получить весь текст

```
String text = ((JTextArea)choiceFile.getComponentAt(choiceFile.getSelectedIndex())).getText();
```